# Bug when marking a question as duplicate

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, flags

I saw this bug mentioned in image below, where in I was about to mark the question as duplicate..

[image]

Has you can see there is no radio buttons to select and go further.. And I am stuck..

Is this a **KNOWN bug**..

I am using Mozilla Firefox Browser..

**Edit:-**

As guided by @AzizShaikh, This kind of behaviour is observed when you have already flagged a post. In my opinion, I think the page as I mentioned above should not have come in first place, I mean don't allow the user to enter **it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate section** if his vote has been posted successfully for that section rather than showing ***go nowhere Im lost Screen ..***

Can we do something about this...??

Comment: This happens when you have already flagged a post. Are you able to see radio buttons for other posts?

Comment: @Aziz Shaikh hmm, I think you are right, b'coz I can see in helpful post section, but I dont understand when did that happen. If that would have happen in case of double- clicking or something I should be notified, I mean we normally get confirmation that moderator will look in this matter, but I got none of this message.

Comment: @AzizShaikh And as rightly said, 'Only one flag post per question' then **why does the flag link doesn't get disabled soon after the question being flagged.**

Comment: "why does the flag link doesn't get disabled soon after the question being flagged" because you may still flag the same post as spam, offensive, or low quality.

Comment: @AzizShaikh hmm... that says all.. Even still I think the page as I mentioned above should not have come in first place, I mean don't allow the user to enter **it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate**  section if his vote has been posted successfully for that section rather than showing *go nowhere Im lost Screen* ..

Comment: Now this (don't allow the user to enter it doesn't belong here, or it is a duplicate section if his vote has been posted successfully) could become a [meta-tag:discussion] or [meta-tag:feature-request] question.  You may edit this post accordingly if you want. Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *I think the page as I mentioned above should not have come in first
>   place, I mean don't allow the user to enter it doesn't belong here, or
>   it is a duplicate section if his vote has been posted successfully for
>   that section rather than showing go nowhere Im lost Screen ..*

This has now been implemented.. when you flag an already flagged question as duplicated you now get informed right away as below..

[image]

So, nomore Im lost screen anymore...**CHEERS!!**

*P.S.. Answering my own question since the feature request is now been completed.*